# Adding LIMIT to pg sql query returns just one row duplicated as many times as the limit says

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select qt.title, qia.text_data
from qt,
     qia,
     qi
     q,
     spam_flag
where qt.quiz_id = qi.quiz_id
  and qia.quiz_item_id = qi.id
  and q.id = qi.quiz_id
  and q.course_id = 'course-id'
  and qi.type = 'essay'
  and qia.quiz_answer_id in (select spam_flag.quiz_answer_id from spam_flag group by spam_flag.quiz_answer_id having count(*)>=0)
  and LENGTH(qia.text_data) > 20
  limit 100;
```

Without the last argument

> limit 100;

the query returns a list of unique rows. But when I add it, it returns just a copy of a single row duplicated as many times as is the limit. What could cause this? This is PostgreSQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably because of your first 100 title and text_data are the same. Moreover with so many joins (I recommend you to use ISO sintax to join tables). Add `select distinct` to your query if that's what you want (but you will  likely get just 1 record)

Comment: I'm guessing you have a cartesian join.  you are probably missing a join.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the join condition for `spam_flag`, so you are getting each result row as often as there are rows in the `spam_flag` table (thus making it live up to its name).

Instead of commas in the `FROM` clause, you should use the explicit `JOIN` syntax. Then that could not happen.